# Why is my variable not passing all the data to a text file in my batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to parse a file that contains data, it has some numbers which I want to parse, store and use them as variables in the future. The problem is, these numbers are updated often so that's why I'm parsing them whenever I run my script.

The problem, is that when I collect the data as a variable in a for loop, it's not getting passed to my text file properly.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


for /f "skip=104 eol=/ tokens=4 delims=," %%A in (file location) do (
echo %%A
echo %%A > UICNumbers.txt
)
```

This is the output of the echo %%A command:

> ```
> UIC00000701991
> UIC00000710996
> UIC00001701890
> UIC00002701890
> UIC00001701898
> UIC00002701898
> ```

When I open the UICNumbers.txt file all I see listed is:

> ```
> UIC00002701898
> ```

which is the last entry in the for loop variable. I tried changing the output to >> but this means every time I run the command it repeats every entry.

Comment: `>` is for overwriting existing files, `>>` is for adding to existing files. If you don't want data there from multiple runs, delete the file before running the loop.

Comment: It is much faster and better to use `(for /f "skip=104 eol=/ tokens=4 delims=," %%A in (file location) do echo %%A)>UICNumbers.txt`. This command line first creates the file `UICNumbers.txt` with overwriting a perhaps existing file with that name. The file is kept open now on running the __FOR__ command line with redirecting the output into the file. After the __FOR__ loop finished, the file `UICNumbers.txt` is closed and contains all lines output during __FOR__ execution. There is no trailing space at end of each line as with your posted command line.

Comment: Your command line results in opening the output file `UICNumbers.txt` with overwriting an existing file as from previous loop iteration, writing the line output by `echo` with trailing space because of a space left to `>` into the file and closing the output file. There could be used `>>` instead of `>` in your command line, but that would result nevertheless in opening the file five times, appending the line at end of the file, and closing the file five times on writing five lines into the file. That is not very efficient, especially on writing thousands of lines into the output file.